# Access to another file from index.php

Tags: php

I have problem with access to file.
I have folders and files:

> public/index.php
>
> app/doit.php

When I use `header('Location: ../app/doit.php');` im my index.php, I have error: Object not found!

My site starts with public/index.php

How to have access to doit.php?

Comment: Where is `app/doit.php` in relation to `public`?  Show the path all the way back to common directories....

Comment: `app` and `public` are in the same level

Comment: I think you cannot redirect to a file that is outside your public path... you would need to route it in a different way

Comment: idd, sounds like the hosting is only allowing to use the public folder, you most likley dont need the redirect, you need `include` or `require` function to the doit.php and there you can execute the code

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Location: ../app/doit.php');
```

it's mean redirect to http://yourhost/public/app/doit.php

to redirect using this code, you must moving app folder to inside public folder

folder structure must be like this `public/app/doit.php`